# How to arrange output of grep command in linux

Tags: linux, bash, grep

i have the following code in my shell script

```
grep -r $1 $2*
```

this code is working perfectly and i get the output like

`/opt/tibco/scripts/nevin/sample:tibco` in one line.

but i need to know is there any way to arrange the output like the following

```
FILE_LOCATION                       NAME       String
______________________________________________________

/opt/tibco/scripts/nevin/          sample     tibco
```

Comment: I'd say using pipe and sed is the best way to format the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pipe the output through `sed` as shown below:

```
grep -r $1 $2* | sed -r 's|(.*)/(.*):(.*)|\1 \2 \3|g'
```